# Decidability of whether CFL = RL

Tags: computability, formal-grammars, undecidability, decision-problem

Let L1 be a language generated by a CFG. 
Let L2 be a language generated by a regular grammar.
Is L1 = L2 ?

Is the above problem decidable or undecidable ?

---

If L1 = L2 then L1 $\cap$ L2' = $\phi$

So the above problem can be written as

CFL $\cap$ RL = $\phi$ or CFL = $\phi$ which is decidable.

So the answer should be decidable according to me but my professor marked it wrong saying it's undecidable

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Note that CFL is typically used to denote the class of *all* context-free languages. That makes your post confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> If $L_1 = L_2$ then $L_1 \cap \overline{L_2} = \emptyset$

While that is true, the reverse is false. The right-hand side is also true if $L_2 \supsetneq L_2$. Therefore, deciding the right-hand side does not solve equality.

Comment: Can we check (L1 $\cap$ L2') $\cup$ (L1' $\cap$ L2) = $\phi$ to solve the question?

Comment: @Zephyr For basic set theory, I suggest you freshen up your basics, e.g. using the Book of Proof. For follow-up computability questions, please post a new question. (You may want try and prove your professor's claim first.)